# Trying to use PowerShell to copy text file content from my local machine and have it added to another file in a Linux server

Tags: linux, powershell

I have a text file that contains server names that I want added to another file that is stored on a Linux server. What command would I need use to have the content of one text file added to another file stored in Linux. The file in Linux should still retain any information already stored on it. The file is related to Puppet `autosign.conf`. The script below is what I am using to read the csv file I have that contains a list of server names I need. The script essentially pulls the only the server names in a way I want them listed. I just now need the command to append my results onto the file in Linux.

```
$data =
    Get-Content "C:\dev\Scripts\Admin Scripts\Environment Deployment\vms2deploy.csv" |
    Select-Object -skip 1 |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -header name 
$myhosts = foreach ($item in $data) { Write-Output $item.name } 
$myhosts >> 'c:\temp\host_list.txt'
```

Update:

Atfer reading the suggestion below i was struck with a thought and came up with these commands to run to solve my issue.

Set-SCPFile -ComputerName servername -Credential (Get-Credential) -LocalFile "c:\temp\host_list.txt" -RemotePath "/home/puppetmaster" 
Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command "cat host_list.txt >> autosign.conf"

Doing this I was able to send my file up to the server and then have it appended to where i want it. The new issue is the autosign.conf seems to be binary and my text file is utf-16le. how would I change the text file to binary so when appended it wont have problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the other answers, I was struck with a thought and came up with these commands to run to solve my issue.

```
Set-SCPFile -ComputerName servername -Credential (Get-Credential) -LocalFile "c:\temp\host_list.txt" -RemotePath "/home/puppetmaster"
Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command "cat host_list.txt >> autosign.conf"
```

Doing this I was able to send my file up to the server and then have it appended to where i want it.

Answer (score 2):

One typically has an SFTP access to a Linux server.

So, use any SFTP client that supports file appending.

For example with [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation), you can use the following command in your PowerShell script.

```
& winscp.com /log=log.log /command `
    "open sftp://username:password@example.com -hostkey=""...""" `
    "put -append c:\temp\host_list.txt /remote/path/list.txt" `
    "exit"
```

You can have [WinSCP GUI generate a command-line template for the SFTP upload](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating) for you.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: I was thinking if the file copy was scheduled, that a cron on the Linux side could perform the line addition and truncate the original file, depending which copy option worked for the OP.  But that would just end up a bit messy, so this is a better answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the contents of the CSV into a file in bash, you'll first want to copy the file to the Linux machine (WinSCP command line tools would work for example) and th.en append in bash using:

```
cat textile1 >> textfile2
```

If the windows server has IIS installed you could make it available on a private IP and curl from the Linux machine:

```
curl http://192.168.120.10/textfile1 >>  textfile2
```

You could make the file available over an SMB share either, if that was a suitable option, but depends on environment. That would look something like:

```
cat smb://server1/share1/textfile1 >> textfile2
```